# Storing named data, where the 'name' is larger than the 'data'?

Tags: c++

I'm writing the logic portion of a game, and want to create, retrieve, and store values (integers) to keep track of progress.  For instance, a door would create the pair (`"location.room.doorlock"`, `0`) in an std::map, and unlocking this door would set that value to `1`.  Anytime the player wants to go through this door, it would retrieve the value by that keyname to see if it's passable.  (Just an example, but it's important that this information exist outside of the "door" object itself, as characters or other events might retrieve this data and act on it.)

The problem though is that the name (or map key) itself is far larger than the data it's referring to, which seems wasteful, and feels 'wrong' as a result.

Is there a commonly used or best approach for storing this type of data, one where the key isn't so much larger than the data itself?

It is possible to know how much space to allocate at compile time for the progress data itself, if it's important.  It need not use `std::map` either, so long as I don't have to use raw array indices to get or store data.

Comment: This is called **premature optimization**. As long as the code is readable and easy to work with, don't worry about the size of the keys; do you know how much a hundred characters of memory costs?

Comment: @Beta - I'm not worried about the cost of the keys themselves.  But the cost makes it smell funny to me.  I wanted to ask if there are proven methods for this type of database, before I begin writing the large bulk of code that's going to rely on it, is all.  If an std::map used like this is fine though, I'll just keep truckin' with it, aha

Comment: Without knowing more about the game, it's hard to say whether this approach is best. I'd wrap the data structure in a `DungeonState` class, so that I could change the implementation easily later, without disturbing the code that relies on it.

Comment: @Beta - That's a good idea actually, probably should've done that to start with.  I'll wrap the structure up then, and worry about the implementation later, so long as it works for now

Comment: Personally, I would use a component system. You have a generic game object (you don't inherit more specific types like "door"), you attach components to it (a slot for each). These component types each hold graphics, physics, logic objects to execute/update, and data that can be seen by other pieces of logic attached to other generic game objects. Input and sound is queried for and triggered by the logic objects. Having a physics component means an object is in the world, and it stores a list of other physics objects that physics object has interacted with this frame.

Comment: Any object interacting with the door knows it touched something, can get the attached game object, then can query it's data object if it has door data, and if so get the data out, modify it, ect. If you need to find this object globally you probably need to store a pointer to it, or have a map to look it up from an ID, stored somewhere globally to the level object.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have two options, if you really want to diminish the size of the string (although the string length does not seem to be that bad at all).

You can either just change your naming conventions or implement hashing. Hashing can be implemented in the form of a hashmap (also known as an unordered map) or by hand (you can create a small program that hashes your names to an int, then use that as a pair). Hashmaps/unordered maps are probably your best bet, as there is a lot of support code out there for it and you don't run the risk of having to deal with bugs in your own programs.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/